# AngularJS: cleanest way to achieve controllers prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, controller

I've browsed a lot of blogs & stackoverflow threads to find the best way to achieve prototypal inheritance for sibling controllers, it led me to study 3 solutions. None is perfect, each one has its drawbacks, so I was wondering if they could be improved, or if someone has a better solution.

Solution 1:

```
// helper function to achieve prototypal inheritance
angular.inherit = function (childCtor, parentCtor) {
    childCtor.super = function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        parentCtor.apply(args.shift(), args);
    };
    childCtor.prototype = Object.create(parentCtor.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: childCtor,
            enumerable: false
        }
    });
    return this;
};


angular.module('test', [])

    // simple service
    .factory('animalService', function() {
        return {
            getScream: function(specy) {
                switch (specy.toLowerCase()) {
                    case 'cat':
                        return 'Meeeeoooow';
                    case 'dog':
                        return 'Waaaaaaarf';
                }
                return '???';
            }
        };
    })

    // AnimalController logic encapsulated in a factory
    .factory('AAnimalController', function ($window, animalService) {

        function AAnimalController($scope, specy) {
            this._name = 'name me!';
            this._specy = specy || 'Animal';

            $scope.$on('cat:mew', react.bind(this));
        }

        function react() {
            if (this.specy === 'Dog') {
                console.log('A cat is around?!? Attack!!!');
            }
        }

        AAnimalController.prototype = {
            introduceItself: function() {
                return 'Hello, my name is "' + this.name + '" and I\'m a ' + this.specy.toLowerCase();
            },

            scream: function() {
                $window.alert(animalService.getScream(this.specy));
            },

            get name() {
                return this._name;
            },
            set name(value) {
                this._name = value;
            },

            get specy() {
                return this._specy;
            }
        };

        return AAnimalController;
    })


    .controller('AnimalController', function ($scope, AAnimalController) {
        return new AAnimalController($scope);
    })


    .controller('DogController', function ($scope, $window, AAnimalController, $controller) {

        function DogController() {
            DogController.super(this, $scope, 'Dog');

            this.fetchStick = function() {
                $window.alert('Here\'s your stick, master!');
            };
        }

        angular.inherit(DogController, AAnimalController);

        return new DogController();
    })


    .controller('CatController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $window, AAnimalController) {

        function CatController() {
            CatController.super(this, $scope, 'Cat');

            this.purr = function() {
                $window.alert('Rrrrrrrr!');
            };

            this.scream = function() {
                AAnimalController.prototype.scream.call(this);
                $rootScope.$broadcast('cat:mew');
            };
        }

        angular.inherit(CatController, AAnimalController);

        return new CatController();
    })
;
```

Cons: can't directly inherit from an angular controller, so we need to encapsulate the base controller logic in a factory, and then to create the corresponding angular base controller by instanciating the base controller class.

JSBin: fipujoxube/edit?html,js,console,output

Solution 2 (from http://ng.malsup.com/#!/controller-inheritance-simplified):

```
// helper function to achieve controller inheritance
var ngModule = angular.module;
angular.module = function() {
    var mod = ngModule.apply(this, arguments);

    mod.inheritController = function(name, inheritFrom, Ctor) {
        this.controller(name, function ($scope, $controller, $injector) {
            var locals = { $scope: $scope, this: this };
            console.log($controller(inheritFrom, locals));
            Ctor.prototype = $controller(inheritFrom, locals);
            locals.superCtrl = Ctor.prototype;
            return $injector.instantiate(Ctor, locals);
        });
        return this;
    };

    return mod;
};


angular.module('test', [])

    // service example
    .factory('animalService', function() {
        return {
            getScream: function(specy) {
                switch (specy.toLowerCase()) {
                    case 'cat':
                        return 'Meeeeoooow';
                    case 'dog':
                        return 'Waaaaaaarf';
                }
                return '???';
            }
        };
    })

    .controller('AnimalController', function ($scope, $window, animalService) {

        // 'PRIVATE' PROPERTIES
        this._name = 'name me!';
        this._specy = 'Animal';

        // PUBLIC METHODS
        /*this.listenForCat = function() {
            $scope.$on('cat:mew', react.bind(this));
        };*/

        this.introduceItself = function() {
            return 'Hello, my name is "' + this._name + '" and I\'m a ' + this._specy.toLowerCase();
        };

        this.scream = function() {
            $window.alert(animalService.getScream(this._specy));
        };

        Object.defineProperties(this, {
            name: {
                get: function() {
                    return this._name;
                },
                set: function(value) {
                    this._name = value;
                }
            },

            specy: {
                get: function() {
                    return this._specy;
                }
            }
        });

        // PRIVATE METHODS
        function react() {
            if (this.specy === 'Dog') {
                console.log('A cat is around? Attack!!');
            }
        }

        $scope.$on('cat:mew', react.bind(this));
    })

    .inheritController('DogController', 'AnimalController', function ($window, superCtrl) {
        this._specy = 'Dog';
        this.fetchStick = function() {
            $window.alert('Here\'s your stick, master!');
        };

        this.listenForCat();
    })

    .inheritController('CatController', 'AnimalController', function ($rootScope, $window, superCtrl) {
        this._specy = 'Cat';

        this.purr = function() {
            $window.alert('Rrrrrrrr!');
        };

        this.scream = function() {
            superCtrl.scream.call(this);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('cat:mew');
        };
    })
;
```

Cons: can't attach methods to prototype, so base controller 'this' always refers to base controller context, not inherited controllers.

JSBin: hvagonenowe/edit?html,js,console,output

Solution 3 (with RequireJS or AlmondJS):

```
define('inherit', function() {
    function inherit(childCtor, parentCtor) {
        childCtor.super = function() {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            parentCtor.apply(args.shift(), args);
        };
        childCtor.prototype = Object.create(parentCtor.prototype, {
            constructor: {
                value: childCtor,
                enumerable: false
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

    return inherit;
});

define('animalService', function() {

    function animalService() {

        return {
            getScream: function(specy) {
                switch (specy.toLowerCase()) {
                    case 'cat':
                        return 'Meeeeoooow';
                    case 'dog':
                        return 'Waaaaaaarf';
                }
                return '???';
            }
        };
    }

    return animalService;
});


define('AnimalController', ['animalService'], function (animalService) {

    animalService = animalService();

    function AnimalController($scope) {
        this._name = 'name me!';
        this._specy = 'Animal';

        $scope.$on('cat:mew', react.bind(this));
    }

    AnimalController.prototype = {
        introduceItself: function() {
            return 'Hello, my name is "' + this.name + '" and I\'m a ' + this.specy.toLowerCase();
        },

        scream: function() {
            window.alert(animalService.getScream(this.specy));
        },

        get name() {
            return this._name;
        },
        set name(value) {
            this._name = value;
        },

        get specy() {
            return this._specy;
        }
    };

    function react() {
        if (this.specy === 'Dog') {
            console.log('A cat is around?!? Attack!!!');
        }
    }

    return AnimalController;
});

define('DogController', ['AnimalController', 'inherit'], function (AnimalController, inherit) {

    function DogController($scope, $window) {
        DogController.super(this, $scope);
        this._specy = 'Dog';

        this.fetchStick = function() {
            $window.alert('Here\'s your stick, master!');
        };
    }

    inherit(DogController, AnimalController);

    return DogController;
});

define('CatController', ['AnimalController', 'inherit'], function (AnimalController, inherit) {

    function CatController($rootScope, $scope, $window, animalService) {
        CatController.super(this, $scope);
        this._specy = 'Cat';

        this.purr = function() {
            $window.alert('Rrrrrrrr!');
        };

        this.scream = function() {
            AnimalController.prototype.scream.call(this);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('cat:mew');
        };
    }

    inherit(CatController, AnimalController);

    return CatController;
});

require([
    'animalService',
    'AnimalController',
    'DogController',
    'CatController'
], function (animalService, AnimalController, DogController, CatController) {

    angular.module('test', [])
        .factory('animalService', animalService)
        .controller('AnimalController', AnimalController)
        .controller('DogController', DogController)
        .controller('CatController', CatController)
    ;

    angular.bootstrap(document, ['test']);
});
```

Cons:

- verbose
- additional 3rd party library
- outside the angular 'world', we
  need to invoke a factory module to gain access to its public methods

JSBin: yagahofefo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Or you could prefer composition to inheritance http://www.sitepoint.com/tidy-angular-controllers-factories-services/

Comment: Yes, but if you're in a situation where performance does matter (multiple controllers that share a common behaviour), inheritance would be best suited, as composition would cause shared methods to be created as many as times as controllers number.

Comment: If you look at your logic, you could easily have a data object, animal, with properties that the controller methods then use. So you'd set up the animal with a reaction, a scream, etc. These could even be set outside your Controller so your Controller doesn't need to know anything about how that happens. Then your getScream() would be return animal.scream, your react() would be console.log(animal.reaction), etc. I'll try to remember to do you a plunker this weekend.